# Python: simple example trying to create a unix command-line executable - why won't it work?

Tags: python, unix, executable

```
PROMPT> which python
/usr/local/bin/python

PROMPT> ls -al
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   3 jon   102B Aug 27 20:15 ./
drwxrwxr-x  21 jon   714B Aug 27 20:15 ../
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jon    54B Aug 27 20:15 build*

PROMPT> cat build
#! /usr/local/bin/ python
print 'hello world - build'

PROMPT> ./build
-bash: ./build: /usr/local/bin/: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, I edited the file to remove the space before the word python on the first line, and that seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the spaces in `#! /usr/local/bin/ python` so it's `#!/usr/local/bin/python`. You may also want to make it `#!/usr/bin/env python`, which will select the [first Python interpreter in your path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script), but that's not recommended for published modules. (Although, neither is `/usr/local/bin/python`).

Comment: Thanks -- I just figured that out.  What I would really like to do, however, is have the first line read something like `#! $APP_HOME/app_venv/bin/python` - is there any way I can use an environment variable in the first line?

Comment: @JonCrowell - You can't really, see *[How can I use environment variables in my shebang?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20880/how-can-i-use-environment-variables-in-my-shebang)*. (*Shebang* line refers to the `#!...` line.)

Comment: Note also that you still have a space after `!` in your comment!

Comment: @JonCrowell - My workflow in virtualenvs is to have a single bash/sh script that contains the `$PATH` modifications, etc. I need, and do `. venv-p2.sh` (or `. venv-p3.sh`, `. venv-num.sh`, etc). Clunky, but I don't know of a simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Your shebang has too many spaces. Try

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
```

Another common form calls 'env' to find which python to use so that you are not dependent on paths that tend to be different depending on how python was installed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Answer (score 2):

You have space between `/bin/` and `python`.

HTH, Phil